# Parametrize a Python class

Tags: python, class, oop

Is there any way to parametrize a class in Python? The parametrized class may look something like this:

```
class FIELDSerializer:
    FIELD = serializers.CharField(source='get_FIELD_display', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = {FIELD}
```

Which would need to create the following three classes:

```
class NameSerializer:
    name = serializers.CharField(source='get_name_display', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = {'name'}

class CategorySerializer:
    category = serializers.CharField(source='get_category_display', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = {'category'}

class StateSerializer:
    state = serializers.CharField(source='get_state_display', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = {'state'}
```

Is this possible or not?

Comment: Is this Django and Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with a factory function, although it's not completely trivial to get the internal variables (attributes) as you want them:

```
def factory(FIELDname):

    class FIELDSerializer:

        class Meta:
            model = None
            fields = {FIELDname}

     settatr(FIELDSerializer, FIELDname, serializers.CharField(source=f'get_{FIELDname}_display', required=False))

     return FIELDSerializer

CategorySerializer = factory('category')
StateSerializer = factory('state')
NameSerializer = factory('name')
```

The [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) allows us to set the name of attribute to the `FIELDname` string. (Thanks to [@Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice) and [@juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) for this idea.)

I don't know if there's any easy way to avoid the repetition of the field name and the desired class name when you call the factory without using something like [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) (which is perfectly legal but usually leaves programmers with a bad taste in their mouths).

Comment: Could you use `setattr()` to set a field with the correct name? Or is that only for instance fields and not class fields? (DISCLAIMER: I'm a curious 3rd party, not the OP.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, you could, `setattr` works on any object, and a class is just an object, like any other in this regard.

Comment: A warning, this looks like it may be Django, in which case, there is some metaclass magic that might make this not work out so cleanly, but this is definitely valid for the class definitions the op wrote